# How to make a loop or something that does a task every 5 seconds and then reset itself?

Tags: java, for-loop, seconds

I need to have the for loop at the bottom do everything in the body every 5 seconds but it's not working for some reason! Sorry if this sounds very dumb, I am very new to java! If you could help, that'd be great! Thanks! :)

```
package rBP;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Main extends Applet implements MouseListener {
public void init() {
    super.init();
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public long numClicks = 0; // 16385
public int autoFingerNum = 0;
public int faultyButtonNum = 0;
public int slickButtonNum = 0;
public int coolButtonNum = 0;
public int heatSinkNum = 0;
public int superButtonNum = 0;
public int aFCost = 30;
public int aFValue = 1;
public int fBCost = 75;
public int fBValue = 3;
public int slBCost = 300;
public int slBValue = 10;
public int cBCost = 1000;
public int cBValue = 25;
public int hSCost = 5000;
public int hSValue = 80;
public int suBCost = 10000;
public int suBValue = 200;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.setSize(1010, 360);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1010, 360); // background
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(47, 47, 205, 205); // button outline
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(50, 50, 200, 200); // button
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(2, 5, 290, 30); // yellow boxes
    g.fillRect(300, 25, 100, 250);
    g.fillRect(410, 25, 100, 250);
    g.fillRect(520, 25, 100, 250);
    g.fillRect(630, 25, 100, 250);
    g.fillRect(740, 25, 100, 250);
    g.fillRect(850, 25, 100, 250);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(300, 100, 400, 100); // lines on yellow boxes
    g.drawLine(410, 100, 510, 100);
    g.drawLine(520, 100, 620, 100);
    g.drawLine(630, 100, 730, 100);
    g.drawLine(740, 100, 840, 100);
    g.drawLine(850, 100, 950, 100);
    g.drawLine(300, 190, 400, 190);
    g.drawLine(410, 190, 510, 190);
    g.drawLine(520, 190, 620, 190);
    g.drawLine(630, 190, 730, 190);
    g.drawLine(740, 190, 840, 190);
    g.drawLine(850, 190, 950, 190);
    g.fillRect(307, 197, 86, 71); // boxes around "buy" buttons
    g.fillRect(417, 197, 86, 71);
    g.fillRect(527, 197, 86, 71);
    g.fillRect(637, 197, 86, 71);
    g.fillRect(747, 197, 86, 71);
    g.fillRect(857, 197, 86, 71);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(310, 200, 80, 65); // red "buy" buttons
    g.fillRect(420, 200, 80, 65);
    g.fillRect(530, 200, 80, 65);
    g.fillRect(640, 200, 80, 65);
    g.fillRect(750, 200, 80, 65);
    g.fillRect(860, 200, 80, 65);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("Number of Points: " + numClicks, 5, 25); // num of points
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 20));
    g.drawString("DO", 135, 120);
    g.drawString("NOT", 127, 150);
    g.drawString("PRESS", 115, 180);
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 16));
    g.drawString("AutoFinger", 310, 50);
    g.drawString("FaultyButton", 411, 50);
    g.drawString("SlickButton", 524, 50);
    g.drawString("CoolButton", 635, 50);
    g.drawString("HeatSink", 754, 50);
    g.drawString("SuperButton", 851, 50);
    g.drawString("+1p/5s", 310, 75);
    g.drawString("+3p/5s", 434, 75);
    g.drawString("+10p/5s", 540, 75);
    g.drawString("+40p/5s", 648, 75);
    g.drawString("+100p/5s", 756, 75);
    g.drawString("+500p/5s", 866, 75);
    g.drawString("Buy: 30P", 315, 240);
    g.drawString("Buy: 75P", 425, 240);
    g.drawString("Buy: 300P", 530, 240);
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 15));
    g.drawString("Buy: 1000P", 642, 240);
    g.drawString("Buy: 5000P", 752, 240);
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 13));
    g.drawString("Buy: 10000P", 862, 240);
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("aFNumber: " + autoFingerNum, 305, 150);
    g.drawString("fBNumber: " + faultyButtonNum, 415, 150);
    g.drawString("sBNumber: " + slickButtonNum, 525, 150);
    g.drawString("cBNumber: " + coolButtonNum, 635, 150);
    g.drawString("hSNumber: " + heatSinkNum, 745, 150);
    g.drawString("sBNumber: " + superButtonNum, 855, 150);

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if ((e.getX() > 50 && e.getX() < 250)
            && (e.getY() > 50 && e.getY() < 250)) {
        numClicks++;
        repaint();
    }
    if ((e.getX() > 310 && e.getX() < 390)
            && (e.getY() > 200 && e.getY() < 265)
            && numClicks > (aFCost - 1)) {
        autoFingerNum++;
        numClicks -= aFCost;
        repaint();
    }
    if ((e.getX() > 420 && e.getX() < 500)
            && (e.getY() > 200 && e.getY() < 265)
            && numClicks > (fBCost - 1)) {
        faultyButtonNum++;
        numClicks -= fBCost;
        repaint();
    }
    if ((e.getX() > 530 && e.getX() < 610)
            && (e.getY() > 200 && e.getY() < 265)
            && numClicks > (slBCost - 1)) {
        slickButtonNum++;
        numClicks -= slBCost;
        repaint();
    }
    if ((e.getX() > 640 && e.getX() < 720)
            && (e.getY() > 200 && e.getY() < 265)
            && numClicks > (cBCost - 1)) {
        coolButtonNum++;
        numClicks -= cBCost;
        repaint();
    }
    if ((e.getX() > 750 && e.getX() < 830)
            && (e.getY() > 200 && e.getY() < 265)
            && numClicks > (hSCost - 1)) {
        heatSinkNum++;
        numClicks -= hSCost;
        repaint();
    }
    if ((e.getX() > 860 && e.getX() < 940)
            && (e.getY() > 200 && e.getY() < 265)
            && numClicks > (suBCost - 1)) {
        superButtonNum++;
        numClicks -= suBCost;
        repaint();
    }

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

public void output() {
    for (int i = 0; i >= 50; i++) {     //<- I just set it at 50 for testing              purposes
                    i = 0;
        numClicks += autoFingerNum * aFValue;
        numClicks += faultyButtonNum * fBValue;
        numClicks += slickButtonNum * slBValue;
        numClicks += coolButtonNum * cBValue;
        numClicks += heatSinkNum * hSValue;
        numClicks += superButtonNum * suBValue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Run the task that you want to repeat on a separate thread. Use `Thread.sleep` for waiting 5 seconds or as much time you need.

Comment: You've posted a lot of code and it looks like only the output` method is relevant here. That said, have a look at [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: try changing the i>=50 to i<=50

Comment: Check java's [Sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) method

Answer (score 1):

Timer + TimerTask might suit your needs.  Here is a code sample:

```
TimerTask task = new MyTask();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, startTime, interval);
```

Where MyTask is:

```
public class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period. This is an efficient means of making processor time available to the other threads of an application or other applications that might be running on a computer system. The sleep method can also be used for pacing, as shown below

```
boolean continueExec = true; //you can use this to exit the loop

public void output() {

   while(this.continueExec ){
        Thread.sleep(5000); //wait 5 seconds     
        numClicks += autoFingerNum * aFValue;
        numClicks += faultyButtonNum * fBValue;
        numClicks += slickButtonNum * slBValue;
        numClicks += coolButtonNum * cBValue;
        numClicks += heatSinkNum * hSValue;
        numClicks += superButtonNum * suBValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). You can schedule it to run your event handling code at any given time interval, or after any scheduled time, and this code will run in a Swing thread from where you can safely manipulate buttons, labels, etc.

If you just want drawing to change periodically, the timer could set some variable that have effect on your painting and then call `repaint()`.

It is more complex to do with your own separate thread as it cannot touch any GUI components, unless SwingUtils.invokeLater or something similar is used.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Thread to execute the statements of `output()`

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                while(true ){

                    numClicks += autoFingerNum * aFValue;
                    numClicks += faultyButtonNum * fBValue;
                    numClicks += slickButtonNum * slBValue;
                    numClicks += coolButtonNum * cBValue;
                    numClicks += heatSinkNum * hSValue;
                    numClicks += superButtonNum * suBValue;
                    repaint();
                    sleep(5000);
                }


            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```